# rails: upvoted pin by user (exists? relation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vote, vote-up-buttons

So I have a pretty simple upvote system in my rails app, that allows users to upvote a pin:

pins_controller.rb

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.friendly.find(params[:id])

  if @pin.votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
     flash[:notice] =  "Thanks for your recommendation."
    redirect_to(pin_path)
  else 
    redirect_to(pin_path)
  end
end
```

And in my view they can upvote by clicking on a button (represented by an icon):
**in app/views/pins/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to upvote_pin_path(pin), method: :post do %>
   <span class="text-decoration: none;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
<% end %>
<%= pluralize(pin.votes.count, "") %></span>
```

I would like to render the icon in different color if the user has already upvoted the pins:
So I thought about using exists?:

```
<%= link_to upvote_pin_path(pin), method: :post do %>

      <% if pin.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).exists? %>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" style="color:red"></i>
      <% else %>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But is doesn't work, instead all icons appears red, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking whether the table exists (check the [exists? documents](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F)).

What you want to do is check if it is `empty?`